# Samba process already running. How to solve?

Tags: samba, samba4

I'm using Internal DNS (**SAMBA_INTERNAL**). But I have the following errors:

`systemctl status samba-ad-dc`

```
samba-ad-dc.service - Samba Active Directory Domain Controller
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-11-25 17:35:00 -03; 12min ago
    Process: 526 ExecStart=/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba -D (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 527 (samba)
      Tasks: 59 (limit: 2340)
     Memory: 216.4M
        CPU: 11.030s
     CGroup: /system.slice/samba-ad-dc.service
             ├─527 samba: root process        .
             ├─528 samba: tfork waiter process(529)
             ├─529 samba: task[s3fs] pre-fork master
             ├─530 samba: tfork waiter process(531)
             ├─531 samba: task[rpc] pre-fork master
             ├─532 samba: tfork waiter process(534)
             ├─533 samba: tfork waiter process(536)
             ├─534 samba: task[nbt] pre-fork master
             ├─535 samba: tfork waiter process(537)
             ├─536 /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -D --option=server role check:inhibit=yes --foreground
             ├─537 samba: task[wrepl] pre-fork master
             ├─538 samba: tfork waiter process(539)
             ├─539 samba: task[ldap] pre-fork master
             ├─540 samba: tfork waiter process(542)
             ├─541 samba: tfork waiter process(546)
             ├─542 samba: task[cldap] pre-fork master
             ├─543 samba: tfork waiter process(544)
             ├─544 samba: task[kdc] pre-fork master
             ├─545 samba: tfork waiter process(548)
             ├─546 samba: task[rpc] pre-forked worker(0)
             ├─547 samba: tfork waiter process(551)
             ├─548 samba: task[drepl] pre-fork master
             ├─549 samba: tfork waiter process(554)
             ├─550 samba: tfork waiter process(553)
             ├─551 samba: task[rpc] pre-forked worker(1)
             ├─552 samba: tfork waiter process(560)
             ├─553 samba: task[kdc] pre-forked worker(0)
             ├─554 samba: task[winbindd] pre-fork master
             ├─555 samba: tfork waiter process(557)
             ├─556 samba: tfork waiter process(562)
             ├─557 samba: task[ntp_signd] pre-fork master
             ├─558 samba: tfork waiter process(566)
             ├─559 samba: tfork waiter process(564)
             ├─560 samba: task[rpc] pre-forked worker(2)
             ├─561 samba: tfork waiter process(565)
             ├─562 samba: task[kdc] pre-forked worker(1)
             ├─563 samba: tfork waiter process(568)
             ├─564 /usr/local/samba/sbin/winbindd -D --option=server role check:inhibit=yes --foreground
             ├─565 samba: task[rpc] pre-forked worker(3)
             ├─566 samba: task[kcc] pre-fork master
             ├─567 samba: tfork waiter process(570)
             ├─568 samba: task[kdc] pre-forked worker(2)
             ├─569 samba: tfork waiter process(572)
             ├─570 samba: task[dnsupdate] pre-fork master
             ├─571 samba: tfork waiter process(573)
             ├─572 samba: task[kdc] pre-forked worker(3)
             ├─573 samba: task[dns] pre-fork master
             ├─580 /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -D --option=server role check:inhibit=yes --foreground
             ├─581 /usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd -D --option=server role check:inhibit=yes --foreground
             ├─582 winbindd: domain child [SAMDOM]
             ├─583 winbindd: idmap child         .
             ├─606 samba: tfork waiter process(607)
             ├─607 samba: task[ldap] pre-forked worker(0)
             ├─608 samba: tfork waiter process(609)
             ├─609 samba: task[ldap] pre-forked worker(1)
             ├─610 samba: tfork waiter process(611)
             ├─611 samba: task[ldap] pre-forked worker(2)
             ├─612 samba: tfork waiter process(613)
             └─613 samba: task[ldap] pre-forked worker(3)

nov 25 17:45:02 DC1 samba[570]: [2022/11/25 17:45:02.945099,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
nov 25 17:45:02 DC1 samba[570]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: update failed: NOTAUTH(BADSIG)
nov 25 17:45:02 DC1 samba[573]: [2022/11/25 17:45:02.999210,  0] ../../source4/auth/gensec/gensec_gssapi.c:1349(gensec_gssapi_check_packet)
nov 25 17:45:02 DC1 samba[573]:   gssapi_check_packet(hdr_signing=0,sig_size=28,data=134,pdu=134) failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]: [2022/11/25 17:45:03.000237,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: ; TSIG error with server: tsig indicates error
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]: [2022/11/25 17:45:03.000309,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: update failed: NOTAUTH(BADSIG)
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]: [2022/11/25 17:45:03.062827,  0] ../../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:85(dnsupdate_nameupdate_done)
nov 25 17:45:03 DC1 samba[570]:   dnsupdate_nameupdate_done: Failed DNS update with exit code 5
```

Here it says that there is already a Samba process running:

`samba -i`

```
samba version 4.17.3 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
ERROR: samba is already running. File /usr/local/samba/var/run/samba.pid exists and process id 527 is running.
```

What should I check in my settings?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what your question is. You've got a samba process running and the first part of your question seems to imply it's expected. Then you ask why you've got a samba process running. Or at least, I think that's what you're asking

Comment: @roaima I don't understand why this "ERROR: samba is already running". With the command "systemctl status samba-ad-dc" I showed that there are DNS errors. I thought the process issue and the DNS issue were related.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking why Samba is running. Are you actually asking about the DNS errors? If so please fix your question so that you're asking the question you want to be answered